# Ensure that if key-word is not present for the category, then the data from its parent should be returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image: Sample Data]

**Sample Input/Output:**

```
Input: 202
Output: ParentCategoryID = 201
        Name = Operating System
        Keywords = Teaching
```

This is what I've tried:

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 T1.[CatergoryId]
  ,T1.[ParentCategoryId]
  ,T1.[Name]
  ,(case when T1.[Keywords] IS null 
   then (select C.[Keywords] FROM [Ingenio].[dbo].[Cat] C 
         where c.[CatergoryId]=T1.[ParentCategoryId])
   else T1.[Keywords] 
   end) as Keywords 
 FROM [Ingenio].[dbo].[Cat] T1  
 join [Ingenio].[dbo].[Cat] T2  
 on T1.CatergoryId =T2.CatergoryId  
 where T1.CatergoryId = 202
```

Query works for 1st level but not for 2nd and nth level.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why the keywords is teaching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [**Recursive CTE**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) for this:

```
DECLARE @param INT = 201

;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT CategoryId, ParentCategoryId, Name, Keywords
   FROM Cat
   WHERE CategoryId = @param

   UNION ALL

   SELECT c1.CategoryId, c1.ParentCategoryId, c1.Name, c1.Keywords
   FROM Cat AS c1
   INNER JOIN CTE AS c2 ON c1.CategoryId = c2.ParentCategoryId  
   WHERE c1.Keywords IS NOT NULL -- terminate if keyword from previous level is not null
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

**Output:**

```
CategoryId  ParentCategoryId    Name        Keywords
------------------------------------------------------
201         200                 Computer    NULL
200         -1                  tutoring    teaching
```

Comment: Given category level as parameter (say N) return the names of the categories which are
of N’th level in the hierarchy (categories with parentId -1 are at 1st level).
Sample Input/Output:
i. Input: 2; Output: 101, 102, 201
ii. Input: 3; Output: 103, 109, 202 Is this can be achieved with Recursive CTE ?

Comment: @Ramesh Yes it certainly can. You can try posting this as a different question.

Comment: i've made here is the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767971/return-the-names-of-the-categories-which-are-of-n-th-level-in-the-hierarchy-cat