# Return the names of the categories which are of N’th level in the hierarchy (categories with parentId -1 are at 1st level)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Sample of Data**

```
WITH sample_data AS (
SELECT  CategoryId,
        ParentCategoryId, 
        Name, 
        Keywords
FROM (VALUES 
(100, -1,   'business',         'Money'),
(200, -1,   'tutoring',         'teaching'),
(101, 100,  'Accountting',      'taxes'),
(102, 100,  'Taxation',         NULL),
(201, 200,  'Computer',         NULL),
(103, 101,  'Corporate Tax',    NULL),
(202, 201,  'operating system', NULL),
(109, 101,  'Small business Tax', NULL)) as c(CategoryId, ParentCategoryId, Name, Keywords)
)
```

**Sample Input/Output:**

```
Input: 2
Output: 101, 102, 201

Input: 3
Output: 103, 109, 202
```

I've been trying out with group by class but it not working, can someone help me out doing it with Recursive CTE(I'm very new to this)

TIA

Comment: Here `Input: 2` - 2 points to which column ? For exa. if its points to `ParentCategoryID` then output should be - `101, 102`. How 201 comes in output ?

Comment: @Krishnraj if parentcategoryid = -1 then it's 1st level, so if input is 2(thats means second level) then if you see category-id 100 and 200 is already at 1st level so category-id 101,102,201 will fall under 2nd level bcoz their parentcatergoryid is lst level(100 and 200).if you see for input 3(thrid level) 103,202,109, parentcategoryid are from second level(101,201,101) so they fall into third level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the followinq query:

```
DECLARE @level INT = 2

;WITH CTE AS (
   -- Start from root categories
   SELECT CategoryId, ParentCategoryId, Name, Keywords, level = 1
   FROM Cat
   WHERE ParentCategoryId = -1

   UNION ALL

   -- Obtain next level category
   SELECT c1.CategoryId, c1.ParentCategoryId, 
          c1.Name, c1.Keywords, level = c2.level + 1
   FROM Cat AS c1
   INNER JOIN CTE AS c2 ON c1.ParentCategoryId   = c2.CategoryId
   WHERE c2.level < @level -- terminate if specified level has been reached
)
SELECT CategoryId
FROM CTE
WHERE level = @level
```

**Output:**

```
CategoryId
==========
201
101
102
```